# Toxgene can not read XML file

Tags: java, xml, sax

I encluntered a prblem in the execution of TOXGENE tool to generate XML file,
when I execute the command with the template file

```
C:\toxgene3.2\samples\catalog>toxgene catalog.tsl
template parsing Done!
Generating 200 elements in author_list: Done!
Reading List genre_lists from ./input/genres.xml"
****Error can not parse files ./input/genres.xml
org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser
```

any suggestions to fix this error

Comment: post the contents of the xml file you are trying to parse.

Answer (score 0):

I suffered this problem and it was caused by the jar files in the last release of **Xerces-J** not being what ToXgene expects.  Try changing the `bin/toxgene` script such that `$XERCES_HOME/xerces.jar` on the `CLASSPATH`.

Answer (score 0):

That's it, which was said by Sudantha, but I found a bug too.
If you is using Windows, it is necessary to edit the line 21 (set TG_CP= ...)
of the bin/toxgene.bat file. You need to remove "$" before "%" characters.

By the way, someone knows where I can to download XBench [1] generator or a ToXgene older version?

[1] https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~tozsu/ddbms/projects/xbench/index.html

Good luck!